# Can some one please explain the following code of threads?

Tags: linux, pthreads

So I am new to system programming and learning threads.What does the term posix means? I need help in understanding the following code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

main()

{

     pthread_t thread1, thread2;

     const char *message1 = "Thread 1";

     const char *message2 = "Thread 2";

     int  iret1, iret2;

     iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);

     iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);


     pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
     pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

     printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
     printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);
     exit(0);

}

void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{

     char *message;
     message = (char *) ptr;
     printf("%s \n", message);

}
```

I dont understand the line:  pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
and the function: void *print_message_function( void *ptr ).

Also, what does the variable iret returns?

Comment: have you tried to google it?: http://bit.ly/1dgpzWt

Comment: Yeah I did but I wanted someone to explain that to me n easier terminologies since I am beginner at this. Thanks though.

Comment: Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) which explains quite well.

Answer (score 1):

It spawns two threads.

Saves their "return values" to variables previously declared.

Joins to threads, basically waits for them to stop.

Prints the variables

### exits with status 0, normal successful exit

posix is a general standard for Unix like operating systems. E.g file structure etc

Answer (score 1):

You should read posix documentation.

> I dont understand the line: pthread_join( thread1, NULL); and the
>   function: void *print_message_function( void *ptr ).

1. `pthread_join` blocks until the thread terminates
2. `void *print_message_function( void *ptr )` is a function returning `void*` and receiving a `void*` as parameter

Again, you should read posix documentation (and learn more C).

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that. can you please tell me why are we passing NULL in  pthread_join( thread1, NULL) ?

Comment: Because the user calling pthread_join is not interested on getting the return code of the thread.